# Postgresql not connecting in django project

Tags: django, postgresql

Working on django project with postgresql database but its giving me error :-

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "dev_onpoint", database "dev_mypsdb", SSL off
```

My database configuration in django is :-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dev_mypsdb',
        'USER': 'dev_onpoint',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

I also checked in postgresql configuration file for port and found that i am using right port number.
Then i checked ph_hba.conf file but because I am not familiar with postgresql database and I am using it first time, that's why I could not understand this file :-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huuUy.png)

Please let me know if i skipped anything in configuration.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pg_hba.conf` file has no access control entry for IPv6 connections, that's why connect from ::1 fails. You can add the following line to your `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             samehost                 md5
```

to allow connections from all local IPs using password authentication (you must restart postgresql after editing this file). For more information refer to the [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: If I add this line it fails restarting postgresql service

Comment: I did not check the postgresql log, I went through the postgres documentation line provided by you and found that I have to add these lines to allow password authentication  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5, after this my project is working fine. Well thanks for giving me the idea about pg_hba file. :)